# Indesign crash when autoflowing text

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a document with 256 pages with one long text auto-flowing for most of the pages. When I edit something indesign has to auto-flow the text, but this takes forever and usually end up crashing the program (computer should be able to handle it - 8 GB of RAM). The text is pasted in the program - not linked from a file.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Graphic Design. What else have you tried? Have you pasted the same copy into another clean InDesign file? Have you broken up your existing file into smaller chunks?

Comment: Hi there! This is more about fixing technology to work as advertised (or tech-support), and I doubt we'll be able to help you here. I'll migrate your question to Super User, a SE site that will guide you better!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest linking from a file.

It should not be a problem, but my guess is that your act of copying the text into memory is part of what is causing your crash.

Grabbing the text from a file should be easier on your computer.